# opencart product URL attribute to be clickable

Tags: php, opencart

I am using Opencart v2.2.0 and I am trying to make the URL attribute of each product clickable. Right now I see the link, but it isn't clickable. I found out the attribute ID of URL attribute and I have the following code:

```
  <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
<?php if ($attribute['attribute_id'] == 102) { ?>
            <tr>
               <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
              <td><a href="<?php echo $attribute['text']; ?>"><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></a></td>
            </tr>
<?php } else { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
```

But it still isn't clickable. Does anyone have a suggestion, please? I do not know what else to do and what am I doing wrong.

Comment: What do you want to echo inside `href`? do you want something like this :`index.php?route=product/product&path=20&product_id=42#attribute_id102`?

Comment: you need to match the link, a link is in this form <a href="http://www.aol.com">text here</a> - make sure you're code does exactly the same. <a href="<?php echo $attribute['text']; ?>"><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></a>

Comment: Thanx, @unixmiah. You helped me, it works!